# Can I run "npm ci" with a custom npmrc file?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to have different paths for different situations for npmrc. For example I want to have a "npmrc.dev" for devs and one for CI "npmrc.ci".

Is this possible? I would be happy with any hack, param, environment variable or some npm module.

Comment: What's the _context_ - what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Devs have separate credentials that the CI. We have different registries with different auth0 tokens. I want to keep the current dev setup that want to do a manual configuration of the toknen while offer a new way to configure it for devs that want to use a generated npmrc.